# How to send Customized User-Agent and Referrer with getJson call?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, getjson

I would like to receive desktop version of page when using getJson from IOS. Is there a way to send customized user-agent and customized referrer when making getJson call ? If the answer is yes how ?

```
 <script>
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.somesite.com/page3.php&callback=?', function(data){
    //$('#output').html(data.contents);

 var siteContents = data.contents;    

//writes to textarea 
document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents ;

</script>
```

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229823/jquery-getjson-how-to-pass-request-headers

Comment: but it doesn't show how to send user-aget with getjson!